# PyAudio generating blank audio files

Tags: python, nlp, pyaudio

I'm trying to go ahead and record audio for further frequency processing later on. I've installed Anaconda and used the pip command on the Anaconda prompt to install pyAudio (latest version) to use with Python 3.5. I've copied the sample record script from the website onto my Spyder Console to start testing but empty .wav files are created. Following is the code I copied

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

It executes without errors and a file is created, though blank. Do I have to configure my computer further, like is it OS version/ driver version specific?

I'm running Windows 8.1 and executing it in my Anaconda Python environment.

Comment: `data = stream.read(CHUNK)` which app set a accessible hardware for you ? You can't access directly to sound card.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, I'm sort of new. I copied the sample recorder code from the official website. How do I access the sound card/ solve my problem?

Comment: I did the same on Ubuntu with same code and pyAudio and Python3 distros. It executes and shows me this during execution 

**JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock**

Perhaps I have to write a separate jack program to initalize? I have no clue and I'm completely new, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `Pulse Audio Sound Controller` for creating virtual device(Sound HUB). I have same fail on `Jack` but no idea `what happening ?`. Haven't any solution about Winblows, so this trick work with UBUNTU.

Comment: hi, I have exactly the same issue... have you already solved it?

Comment: nvm... but microphone was one mute...